# Getting an array to string conversion error

Tags: php, arrays

Can someone help me what's the problem with this code? Im trying to store the fetched data to an array and i want to based on the values of that array. Im getting an error of `Array to string conversion`. The datatype value of an array is `string`

Here's the code.

```
            $sql3 ="SELECT DISTINCT subj_descr FROM subj_enrolled WHERE enroll_ref = '$ref'";
           $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
           $data = array();
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
                      $data[] = array($row['subj_descr']);
              }


            $sql ="SELECT * FROM notification WHERE subj_descr IN ({implode(',', $data})";
           $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

           $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: just remove array inside your while loop, rest everything is fine

Comment: As suggested by @Insomania just remove `array()` from this `array($row['subj_descr'])`;

Answer (score 0):

Remove `array` inside your while loop:

```
$sql3 ="SELECT DISTINCT subj_descr FROM subj_enrolled WHERE enroll_ref = '$ref'";
       $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
       $data = array();
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
                  $data[] = $row['subj_descr'];
          }


        $sql ="SELECT * FROM notification WHERE subj_descr IN ({implode(',', $data})";
       $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

       $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Error on WHERE subj_descr IN ({implode(',', $data})";

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `multidimensional` array and so change this statement

```
$data[] = array($row['subj_descr']);
```

to

```
$data[] = $row['subj_descr'];
```

As `SQL IN` statement always used a single dimensional array so also make change in query where clause.

I have changed all, please try below code:

```
 <?php
    $sql3 ="SELECT DISTINCT subj_descr FROM subj_enrolled WHERE enroll_ref = '$ref'";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
        $data[] = $row['subj_descr'];
    }
    $dataStr = implode(',', $data);

    $sql ="SELECT * FROM notification WHERE subj_descr IN (".$dataStr.")";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    ?>
```

Comment: A little explanation will do to make him understand.

Comment: I'm getting an error of ` mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in` but when i change the it to `IN ('COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 1','COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2'); it's working?

Comment: i tried to put the `$dataStr` to `vardump` i get the output of `string(59) "ENGLISH 2,KUMUNIKASYON,COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2,MATHEMATICS 2" `the $dataStr has a value why is that im getting an error?

Comment: echo this query and run directly in phpmyadmin to check the exact error or may be empty result

Comment: means your query is wrong so mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result error occurred. or did not match any record in database

Answer (score 0):

create a new variable and implode in it.

**Try this**

```
$implodeAray = implode(",", $data);
$sql ="SELECT * FROM notification WHERE subj_descr IN ($implodeAray)";
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of ` mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in` but when i change the it to `IN ('COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 1','COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2'); it's working?

Comment: yes if you have strings in your array then you need to separate it with quote('a','b', 'c').

Comment: remove ` before IN and show your query by echo $sql.

Answer (score 0):

You stored the element of your array inside another array while looping.

Do this:

```
$sql3 ='SELECT DISTINCT subj_descr 
        FROM subj_enrolled 
        WHERE enroll_ref = "$ref"';

$results = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    //Your error was here
    //Each elements is escaped for security reasons
    $data[] = mysqli_escape_string($con,$row['subj_descr']);          
}

//This implodes and puts a single quote around each element
$dataIn= '\'' . implode( '\', \'', $data ) . '\'';

$sql ="SELECT * FROM notification 
       WHERE subj_descr IN ($dataIn)";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of ` mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in` but when i change the it to `IN ('COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 1','COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2'); it's working?

Comment: i tried to put the $dataIn to vardump i get the output of string(59) "ENGLISH 2,KUMUNIKASYON,COMPUTER PROGRAMMING 2,MATHEMATICS 2" the $dataIn has a value why is that im getting an error?

Comment: @wataru I've update the code to wrap each elements in a single quote but you must run mysql_escape_string on each element before builing the array as in `$data[] = mysqli_escape_string($con,$row['subj_descr'])`;

Comment: It's null.. But my database has a 2 records.

Comment: You can check your query again you can rewrite your query this way:  `$sql ="SELECT COUNT(* ) AS total FROM notification WHERE subj_descr IN ($dataIn)";` Then fetch your result this way `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql); echo $row['total']; `